# Solr container goes down every 2 mins

Tags: docker-compose, solr, islandora

I am using islandora digital repository (islandora+fedora+solr) framework,
But I am facing issue with the solr server that it goes down every 2 mins and once I restart it, might works for 1 hour and again goes down.
Note that I am using docker container solr.
When I checked the docker logs I found this

4-Dec-2023 05:08:46.170 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/solr] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.checkCommitted(ResponseFacade.java:514)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:353)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.sendError(SolrDispatchFilter.java:821)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:434)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:181)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:617)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:932)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Note that when I start the solr server alone without any connectivity with islandora, it's working perfectly,
I don't know if there are some queries can cause this or not
The pecs for the solr server is 128 memory and 32 core processor

I've checked all the logs but couldn't find anything

Comment: This log seem to be unrelated to the root cause. What happened before? Any other error messages?
Also, even though the machine has 128GB and 32 cores, the resources for the container might be limited by Docker runtime depending on options you use.